# how to remove non committed objects from context?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using core data and NSFetchedResultsController in an app, for feeding a UIViewTable with Car objects. I have a button that, when tabbed, takes the app to another view when the user can add a new Car. The problem I have is that even if the user doesn't create the car in the second view, it's added to the table. If I restart the application, the Car wasn't added to the DB.

This is related to the fact that I create an instance of the Car in the second view, in the viewDidLoad method, using something like this:

```
    car = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Car" 
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

This is added even if I don't save the context.

I tried to delete the object when the second view is about to be closed, using this:

```
[context deleteObject:car];
```

This partially works. The car is not added to the table in the first page, but looks like the indexes of the data source are altered. If I scroll all the way down I got this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:]: index (9) beyond bounds (9)'
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try delaying the insertion of the new object when the user commits the change.

Only if it's not appropriate:

When the context has changed, NSFetchedResultsController is automatically informed to modify its data passed to the table view controller. However, the table view itself is **not** modified, so you have to update the table view by yourself.

That's why NSFetchedResultsController has a delegate object (conforming to NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol) which is responsible to update the table view.

For example, in CoreDataBooks sample project, you will see delegate methods of this protocol in RootViewController class. The most related delegate method is `controller: didChangeObject: atIndexPath: forChangeType: newIndexPath:`. You may probably want to do something like the following:

```
if (changeType == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];  
}
```

Comment: yes, I had the delegate methods and all the code was commented out. I just delayed the creation of the Managed Object until the end, when I got the confirmation that it should be created.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your car object by passing a `nil` context:

```
car = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Car" 
                              inManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

From there, if the user decides to save it you can move the object to the main context.

The other alternative is to have a separate MOC for this view (which adds unnecessary complications) and then again move the object between contexts if/when required.

Cheers,

Rog

PS: if you're wondering whether you can pass nil as the managedObjectContext, this is straight from Apple's docs on NSManagedObject:

> ...If context is not nil, this method
>   invokes [context insertObject:self]
>   (which causes awakeFromInsert to be
>   invoked)...

More details [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html)

**[EDIT]**

In addition to this, I just came across something interesting when looking at the NSFetchRequest documentation and thought you might want to have a go (I haven't tried myself). It appear that you can tell the fetchRequest whether to include pending changes (i.e. not saved) or not when fetching objects:

`- (void)setIncludesPendingChanges:(BOOL)yesNo`

FYI the default value is YES - more details [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSFetchRequest)

Comment: i couldn't assign a nil context, I got an error. The solution was to create a new class to store the data, and when the user confirms he'she wants to create the record, I use the information from this new class to create it. Thanks for the help.